# More than one 'in' expression within $map

Tags: mongodb

Been recently playing around with an array field within documents of a collection, and was wondering if I could apply more than one expression having `in` is specified in some way?

```
        $project: {
        "new_field": {
            $map: {
                input: "$test", 
                as: "item", 
                in: {$trim: {input: "$$item"}}
            }
        }
    }
```

And trying to avoid performing another projection I was thinking of doing something like this, but just fails with `An object representing an expression must have exactly one field`.

```
        $project: {
        "new_field": {
            $map: {
                input: "$test", 
                as: "item", 
                in: {$trim: {input: "$$item"}, $concat: ["$$item", "testing"]}
            }
        }
    }
```

Is my only option to just do another project step with all the fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply more than one operation. But the output will not be on top of the first expression' result.

**Sample Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      adjustedGrades: {
        $map: {
          input: "$quizzes",
          as: "grade",
          in: [
            {
              $add: [
                "$$grade",
                2
              ]
            },
            {
              $add: [
                "$$grade",
                3
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Difference:**

I specified `in` as array.

in: [
{
$add: [
"$$grade",
2
]
},
{
$add: [
"$$grade",
3
]
}
]

**Sample input:**

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    quizzes: [
      5,
      6,
      7
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    quizzes: []
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    quizzes: [
      3,
      8,
      9
    ]
  }
]
```

**Sample output:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "adjustedGrades": [
      [
        7,
        8
      ],
      [
        8,
        9
      ],
      [
        9,
        10
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "adjustedGrades": []
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "adjustedGrades": [
      [
        5,
        6
      ],
      [
        10,
        11
      ],
      [
        11,
        12
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xedvmZzFkE6)

Comment: Oh, I see! So it's like each expression generate an independent entry... It was an array in origin and has to be after projection. So to preserve the original input I must do it one by one, since one depends on the other and should be sequential, right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. In the documentation also they mentioned that you can pass `an expression`.

Comment: Haha yeah was hoping for a magical miracle which merges both into one but seems that won't make that wish come true! Thanks a lot for the reply, now I know one more thing!